# How to apply filter in ng-repeat for object's fields?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to apply angular filter for selected object field. I have list of statuses ["waiting", "conform", "rac"], when I select a status it should give information of persons in the table which have that status.

For example if some person ticket conform, then when we select `status = conform` then only person shown should have conform ticket. Similarly for waiting and rac

Please see the demo and code. It is not working. Please help..
[Please see the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NBKraD3xbECWHSe7Fd5j?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>Name</tr>
        <tr>Status</tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
        <tr ng-repeat="person in list| filter: status">
          <td>{{person.name}}</td>
          <td>{{person.status}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.status_list=["waiting", "conform", "rac"];
  $scope.list = [
  { 'name': 'A',

    'status':'waiting'
  },
  { 'name': 'B',

     'status':'conform'
  },
  { 'name': 'C',
     'status':'rac'
  }
]
```

Comment: post your filter code also and why you are not using filter in your expression `{{ person.name | status}}`

Comment: What is it that you wish to do with the status field? Sort in alphabetical order on that field?

Comment: the command is `ng-repeat` not `ng-repead`

Comment: @PankajParkar, Hi Pankaj if you are looking opportunity in Bangalore. I can refer you in my company. My company name is Black-Buck Logistic.  You can get more information about this company from 1. http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/tech-news/Logistics-startup-BlackBuck-raises-25-million-from-Tiger-Global-Yuri-Milner/articleshow/50110256.cms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be specific to apply `filter` over `status` property rather than directly using filter which will work as contains filter (use compactor set to `true` for getting exact match). By having contains filter you will get person in list which will have name any one of string which you are searching for `status`

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in list| filter: { status: status}: true">
   <td>{{person.name}}</td>
   <td>{{person.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

> Correct typo of `ng-repead` to `ng-repeat`

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdblKxbSlZ9gZkFekFGm?p=preview)

Comment: I have change the senario, please see this example http://plnkr.co/edit/V8BmdS4ILCPZCSNTQnd2?p=preview

Comment: @user1308874 here is working plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/AAa4REszZf8PLydx9bJ3?p=preview with changed scenario, it wasn't working because you it had status `id` in a string, so remove quotes from it to make it number and there were some mistake in `ng-options`

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in list| filter: status">
```

You had spelled repeat wrong